# Representing database data as classes

Tags: php, mysql, architecture

I have some tables in a database, and I represent each table in PHP code as a class:

```
class User {
  public $id;
  public $login;
  public $password;

  public Role $role;
}
```

All foreign keys are treated as separate objects. Let's say I want to make an SQL query now that returns the above `User` class:

```
$result = ...SELECT
  u.id as user_id,
  u.login as user_login,
  u.password as user_password
  r.id as role_id,
  r.name as role_name
FROM user u
INNER JOIN role r ON u.role_id = r.id;

$u = new User($result['user_id'], $result['user_login'], ...);
```

It's a nice approach, because all data throughout the application is very consistent, but creating such objects as in my example above is a mess. Having more relations can make it even worse.

Is there a better approach to this problem?

Comment: Perhaps consider using an ORM like Doctrine2 that do the grunt work for you?

Comment: you are basically trying to build an ORM, but there are a few tried and tested ones